# Scribe and Atlassian rest

Tags: scribe

I'm trying to use Scribe to use Atlassian Jira using example from here:

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+OAuth+authentication

Anyone have any luck?

Here's what I got:

```
public class JiraAPI extends DefaultApi10a {

static final String BASE = "http://xasdf:8080/plugins/servlet";

 @Override
 public String getAccessTokenEndpoint()
 {
   return BASE + "/oauth/access-token";
 }

 @Override
 public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token requestToken)
 {
   return BASE + "/oauth/authorize?oauth_token="+requestToken.getToken();
 }

 @Override
 public String getRequestTokenEndpoint()
 {
   return BASE + "/oauth/request-token";
 }

 @Override
 public SignatureService getSignatureService() {
    return new RSASha1SignatureService(getPrivateKey());
 }

private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey()
  {
    String str = "MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAmAwggJcAgEAAoGBAMPQ5BCMxlUq2TYy\n"+
                 "iRIoEUsz6HGTJhHuasS2nx1Se4Co3lxwxyubVdFj8AuhHNJSmJvjlpbTsGOjLZpr\n"+
                 "HyDEDdJmf1Fensh1MhUnBZ4a7uLrZrKzFHHJdamX9pxapB89vLeHlCot9hVXdrZH\n"+
                 "nNtg6FdmRKH/8gbs8iDyIayFvzYDAgMBAAECgYA+c9MpTBy9cQsR9BAvkEPjvkx2\n"+
                 "XL4ZnfbDgpNA4Nuu7yzsQrPjPomiXMNkkiAFHH67yVxwAlgRjyuuQlgNNTpKvyQt\n"+
                 "XcHxffnU0820VmE23M+L7jg2TlB3+rUnEDmDvCoyjlwGDR6lNb7t7Fgg2iR+iaov\n"+
                 "0iVzz+l9w0slRlyGsQJBAPWXW2m3NmFgqfDxtw8fsKC2y8o17/cnPjozRGtWb8LQ\n"+
                 "g3VCb8kbOFHOYNGazq3M7+wD1qILF2h/HecgK9eQrZ0CQQDMHXoJMfKKbrFrTKgE\n"+
                 "zyggO1gtuT5OXYeFewMEb5AbDI2FfSc2YP7SHij8iQ2HdukBrbTmi6qxh3HmIR58\n"+
                 "I/AfAkEA0Y9vr0tombsUB8cZv0v5OYoBZvCTbMANtzfb4AOHpiKqqbohDOevLQ7/\n"+
                 "SpvgVCmVaDz2PptcRAyEBZ5MCssneQJAB2pmvaDH7Ambfod5bztLfOhLCtY5EkXJ\n"+
                 "n6rZcDbRaHorRhdG7m3VtDKOUKZ2DF7glkQGV33phKukErVPUzlHBwJAScD9TqaG\n"+
                 "wJ3juUsVtujV23SnH43iMggXT7m82STpPGam1hPfmqu2Z0niePFo927ogQ7H1EMJ\n"+
                 "UHgqXmuvk2X/Ww==";

    try
    {
      KeyFactory fac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
      PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(str.getBytes()));
      return fac.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Scribe has always been easy with other OAuth based providers, but this provider always "oauth_problem=signature_invalid" from debug:

generating signature...
base string is: POST&http%3A%2F%2Fxasdf%3A8080%2Fplugins%2Fservlet%2Foauth%2Frequest-token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dhardcoded-consumer%26oauth_nonce%3D1556398454%26oauth_signature_method%3DRSA-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1357151719%26oauth_version%3D1.0
signature is: AJugUeZGup5dZvjNjx6bec6OrAszZVK+pMrTzahZbbzKzGkbli7okBy2KO5ww+OtqqnHWRgyzfWnQ0k6R5U0JzjR4QiOANJuwV8Un1NTZsrK32daefCp2uZ6W2d2Y/fmIl3toyCjAx41c3oJ78572vVFmBGihHUTUOYTlFP1X3M=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_callback -> oob , oauth_signature -> AJugUeZGup5dZvjNjx6bec6OrAszZVK+pMrTzahZbbzKzGkbli7okBy2KO5ww+OtqqnHWRgyzfWnQ0k6R5U0JzjR4QiOANJuwV8Un1NTZsrK32daefCp2uZ6W2d2Y/fmIl3toyCjAx41c3oJ78572vVFmBGihHUTUOYTlFP1X3M= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 1556398454 , oauth_signature_method -> RSA-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> hardcoded-consumer , oauth_timestamp -> 1357151719 }

using Http Header signature
sending request...
response status code: 401

Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: 'oauth_signature=AJugUeZGup5dZvjNjx6bec6OrAszZVK%2BpMrTzahZbbzKzGkbli7okBy2KO5ww%2BOtqqnHWRgyzfWnQ0k6R5U0JzjR4QiOANJuwV8Un1NTZsrK32daefCp2uZ6W2d2Y%2FfmIl3toyCjAx41c3oJ78572vVFmBGihHUTUOYTlFP1X3M%3D&oauth_signature_base_string=POST%26http%253A%252F%252Ftracker%253A8080%252Fplugins%252Fservlet%252Foauth%252Frequest-token%26oauth_callback%253Doob%2526oauth_consumer_key%253Dhardcoded-consumer%2526oauth_nonce%253D1556398454%2526oauth_signature_method%253DRSA-SHA1%2526oauth_timestamp%253D1357151719%2526oauth_version%253D1.0&oauth_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1'
response body: oauth_signature=AJugUeZGup5dZvjNjx6bec6OrAszZVK%2BpMrTzahZbbzKzGkbli7okBy2KO5ww%2BOtqqnHWRgyzfWnQ0k6R5U0JzjR4QiOANJuwV8Un1NTZsrK32daefCp2uZ6W2d2Y%2FfmIl3toyCjAx41c3oJ78572vVFmBGihHUTUOYTlFP1X3M%3D&oauth_signature_base_string=POST%26http%253A%252F%252Ftracker%253A8080%252Fplugins%252Fservlet%252Foauth%252Frequest-token%26oauth_callback%253Doob%2526oauth_consumer_key%253Dhardcoded-consumer%2526oauth_nonce%253D1556398454%2526oauth_signature_method%253DRSA-SHA1%2526oauth_timestamp%253D1357151719%2526oauth_version%253D1.0&oauth_problem=signature_invalid&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1
    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)

Comment: did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you cannot use Scribe with JIRA/Atlassian OAuth, since Scribe does not support RSA-SHA1 signatures, but this is the only Signature available in Atlassian's OAuth providers.

The only Java library, that I could find, which supports this method is the one used in the example code linked in the questions - the net.oauth one.

Answer (score 1):

I have this working using scribe 1.3.6 using the provided `RSASha1SignatureService`, here's how I'm extracting the private key (from a PKCS#8 PEM file, the one with the `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` header, not the `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY`, which is the SSLeay format)

```
package com.company.client.api;

import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a;
import org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi20;
import org.scribe.model.OAuthConfig;
import org.scribe.model.Token;
import org.scribe.services.RSASha1SignatureService;
import org.scribe.services.SignatureService;

public class JiraApi extends DefaultApi10a {

    private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=%s";
    private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_RESOURCE = "http://localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token";
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_RESOURCE = "http://localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/oauth/access-token";

    @Override
    public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
        return ACCESS_TOKEN_RESOURCE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
        return REQUEST_TOKEN_RESOURCE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthorizationUrl(Token requestToken) {
        return String.format(AUTHORIZE_URL, requestToken.getToken());
    }

    @Override
    public SignatureService getSignatureService() {
        return new RSASha1SignatureService(getPrivateKey());
    }

    private PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
        try {
            byte[] key = Base64.getDecoder().decode(JiraClientImpl.privateKey); // this is the PEM encoded PKCS#8 private key 
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(key);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```